# Pyspark aggregation with random number of row selection by using time column and a duration variable

Tags: python, pyspark

In pyspark, I have a dataframe like the following sample:

```
id, execution_time, sym, qty
========================================
1, 2023-10-27 15:01:24.2200, aa1, 100
2, 2023-10-27 15:15:21.2200, aa1, 250
3, 2023-10-27 15:27:24.2200, aa2, 350
4, 2023-10-27 15:35:25.2200, aa3, 400
5, 2023-10-27 16:00.25.2200, aa3, 500
6, 2023-10-27 16:15:24.2200, aa4, 100
7, 2023-10-27 16:55:24.2200, aa1, 100
8, 2023-10-27 16:50:24.2200, aa2, 100
========================================
```

Now my requirement is this:
I have a 'duration' variable and the value of this variable is 30 # in minutes
Now Starting from the first row I need to apply the value of the duration variable, and then I need to group these rows like the below-
So, in this sample data, after applying the 'duration' variable, I should be able to group till the third row. Because the time of the 4th row is greater than the first row + duration. (we applied duration on the first row)

Now again I need to start from the 4th row and apply the duration variable and this time we should group only rows 4 and 5 because the time of the 6th row is greater than the 4th row + duration. (we applied duration on the 4th row)

Now again I need to start from the 6th row and apply the duration variable and this time we should group only the row 6th,
because Because time of the 7th row is greater than the 6th row + duration. (we applied duration on the 6th row)

In other words:
So after applying the duration on a row's time column (let's say this is our result),
we need to pick all upcoming rows where the next row's time > result and then pick the next row and apply duration.

is it possible to mark all those rows and store this in a new column, which falls under the above condition?
Because later I need to do the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

you could collect all the date rows as a list of structs and then use `aggregate` function to match the end times.

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit('gk')). \
    agg(func.sort_array(func.collect_list(func.struct('id', 'exec_time', 'sym', 'qty'))).alias('bork')). \
    withColumn('bork2',
               func.aggregate(func.expr('slice(bork, 2, size(bork))'),
                              func.array(func.col('bork')[0].withField('end', func.expr('bork[0].exec_time + interval 30 minutes'))),
                              lambda x, y: func.array_union(x,
                                                            func.array(y.withField('end', 
                                                                                   func.when(y.exec_time <= func.element_at(x, -1).end, func.element_at(x, -1).end).
                                                                                   otherwise(y.exec_time + func.expr('interval 30 minutes'))
                                                                                   )
                                                                       )
                                                            )
                              )
               ). \
    selectExpr('inline(bork2)'). \
    withColumn('id_grp', func.collect_list('id').over(wd.partitionBy('end'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----------------------+---+---+----------------------+---------+
# |id |exec_time             |sym|qty|end                   |id_grp   |
# +---+----------------------+---+---+----------------------+---------+
# |1  |2023-10-27 15:01:24.22|aa1|100|2023-10-27 15:31:24.22|[1, 2, 3]|
# |2  |2023-10-27 15:15:21.22|aa1|250|2023-10-27 15:31:24.22|[1, 2, 3]|
# |3  |2023-10-27 15:27:24.22|aa2|350|2023-10-27 15:31:24.22|[1, 2, 3]|
# |4  |2023-10-27 15:35:25.22|aa3|400|2023-10-27 16:05:25.22|[4, 5]   |
# |5  |2023-10-27 16:00:25.22|aa3|500|2023-10-27 16:05:25.22|[4, 5]   |
# |6  |2023-10-27 16:15:24.22|aa4|100|2023-10-27 16:45:24.22|[6]      |
# |7  |2023-10-27 16:55:24.22|aa1|100|2023-10-27 17:25:24.22|[7, 8]   |
# |8  |2023-10-27 16:50:24.22|aa2|100|2023-10-27 17:25:24.22|[7, 8]   |
# +---+----------------------+---+---+----------------------+---------+
```

the `aggregate` functions works like python's `reduce`. it recursively applies a logic to an array's elements. in this case, i keep checking the end date with the `exec_time` and if the `exec_time` is greater than the current end date, the end date is recaluculated using the `exec_time`.

---

```py
# the arrays
data_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit('gk')). \
    agg(func.sort_array(func.collect_list(func.struct('id', 'exec_time'))).alias('bork')). \
    withColumn('bork2',
               func.aggregate(func.expr('slice(bork, 2, size(bork))'),
                              func.array(func.col('bork')[0].withField('end', func.expr('bork[0].exec_time + interval 30 minutes'))),
                              lambda x, y: func.array_union(x,
                                                            func.array(y.withField('end', 
                                                                                   func.when(y.exec_time <= func.element_at(x, -1).end, func.element_at(x, -1).end).
                                                                                   otherwise(y.exec_time + func.expr('interval 30 minutes'))
                                                                                   )
                                                                       )
                                                            )
                              )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |gk |bork                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |bork2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |gk |[{1, 2023-10-27 15:01:24.22}, {2, 2023-10-27 15:15:21.22}, {3, 2023-10-27 15:27:24.22}, {4, 2023-10-27 15:35:25.22}, {5, 2023-10-27 16:00:25.22}, {6, 2023-10-27 16:15:24.22}, {7, 2023-10-27 16:55:24.22}, {8, 2023-10-27 16:50:24.22}]|[{1, 2023-10-27 15:01:24.22, 2023-10-27 15:31:24.22}, {2, 2023-10-27 15:15:21.22, 2023-10-27 15:31:24.22}, {3, 2023-10-27 15:27:24.22, 2023-10-27 15:31:24.22}, {4, 2023-10-27 15:35:25.22, 2023-10-27 16:05:25.22}, {5, 2023-10-27 16:00:25.22, 2023-10-27 16:05:25.22}, {6, 2023-10-27 16:15:24.22, 2023-10-27 16:45:24.22}, {7, 2023-10-27 16:55:24.22, 2023-10-27 17:25:24.22}, {8, 2023-10-27 16:50:24.22, 2023-10-27 17:25:24.22}]|
# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- gk: string (nullable = false)
#  |-- bork: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- exec_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- bork2: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- exec_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in a simple manner.

1. First create a Window spec such that we are collecting all the ids which fall within the window_spec.
2. Take the count of those collected ids list and store it inside a column.
3. Extract out the id and count into a separate list for sequential iterative processing since it is complex and can't be directly achieved within Window function.
4. Process the extracted list of tuples as desired.
5. Create a dataframe from the above processed list.

Here's the python script :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [

[1, "2023-10-27 15:01:24.2200", "aa1", 100],
[2, "2023-10-27 15:15:21.2200", "aa1", 250],
[3, "2023-10-27 15:27:24.2200", "aa2", 350],
[4, "2023-10-27 15:35:25.2200", "aa3", 400],
[5, "2023-10-27 16:00:25.2200", "aa3", 500],
[6, "2023-10-27 16:15:24.2200", "aa4", 100],
[7, "2023-10-27 16:55:24.2200", "aa1", 100],
[8, "2023-10-27 16:50:24.2200", "aa2", 100],


]

columns1 =["id", "execution_time", "sym", "qty"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)

df1 = df1.withColumn("execution_time", F.to_timestamp(F.col("execution_time")))
df1 = df1.withColumn("unix_timestamp", F.unix_timestamp("execution_time"))

df1.show(n=20, truncate=False)

print("dataframe df1 schema")
print(df1.schema)

window_spec = (
    Window
    .orderBy(F.col("unix_timestamp"))
    .rangeBetween(0, 30*60 ) # duration in seconds
)

calculated_columns_df = df1.withColumn("collected_ids", F.collect_list("id").over(window_spec))
calculated_columns_df = calculated_columns_df.withColumn("count_of_ids", F.count("collected_ids").over(window_spec))

print("Calculated Dataframe : Window Aggregation Function Applied")
calculated_columns_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)


collect_id_maxid_pairs = calculated_columns_df.select("id", "unix_timestamp", "count_of_ids").orderBy("unix_timestamp").rdd.map(lambda ele : (int(ele["id"]), int(ele["count_of_ids"]))).collect()

id_list_only = [ele[0] for ele in collect_id_maxid_pairs]
count_list_only = [ele[1] for ele in collect_id_maxid_pairs]

grouped_ids = []

iter_over_count_list =  iter(count_list_only)


try:
    while True:
        element = next(iter_over_count_list)
        print(f"accepted count = {element}")
        grouping_value = id_list_only[: element]
        grouped_ids.append((id_list_only[0], grouping_value))
        id_list_only = id_list_only[element : ]

        for idx in range(element-1):
            discarded_count = next(iter_over_count_list)
            print(f"discarded count = {discarded_count}")

except StopIteration:
    print("Reached the end of the iterator.")


auxilary_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(grouped_ids, ["id", "ids_within_group"])

print("auxilary_df : ")
auxilary_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+
|id |execution_time        |sym|qty|unix_timestamp|
+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+
|1  |2023-10-27 15:01:24.22|aa1|100|1698399084    |
|2  |2023-10-27 15:15:21.22|aa1|250|1698399921    |
|3  |2023-10-27 15:27:24.22|aa2|350|1698400644    |
|4  |2023-10-27 15:35:25.22|aa3|400|1698401125    |
|5  |2023-10-27 16:00:25.22|aa3|500|1698402625    |
|6  |2023-10-27 16:15:24.22|aa4|100|1698403524    |
|7  |2023-10-27 16:55:24.22|aa1|100|1698405924    |
|8  |2023-10-27 16:50:24.22|aa2|100|1698405624    |
+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+

dataframe df1 schema
StructType([StructField('id', LongType(), True), StructField('execution_time', TimestampType(), True), StructField('sym', StringType(), True), StructField('qty', LongType(), True), StructField('unix_timestamp', LongType(), True)])
Calculated Dataframe : Window Aggregation Function Applied

+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+-------------+------------+
|id |execution_time        |sym|qty|unix_timestamp|collected_ids|count_of_ids|
+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+-------------+------------+
|1  |2023-10-27 15:01:24.22|aa1|100|1698399084    |[1, 2, 3]    |3           |
|2  |2023-10-27 15:15:21.22|aa1|250|1698399921    |[2, 3, 4]    |3           |
|3  |2023-10-27 15:27:24.22|aa2|350|1698400644    |[3, 4]       |2           |
|4  |2023-10-27 15:35:25.22|aa3|400|1698401125    |[4, 5]       |2           |
|5  |2023-10-27 16:00:25.22|aa3|500|1698402625    |[5, 6]       |2           |
|6  |2023-10-27 16:15:24.22|aa4|100|1698403524    |[6]          |1           |
|8  |2023-10-27 16:50:24.22|aa2|100|1698405624    |[8, 7]       |2           |
|7  |2023-10-27 16:55:24.22|aa1|100|1698405924    |[7]          |1           |
+---+----------------------+---+---+--------------+-------------+------------+

accepted count = 3
discarded count = 3
discarded count = 2
accepted count = 2
discarded count = 2
accepted count = 1
accepted count = 2
discarded count = 1
Reached the end of the iterator.
 auxilary_df : 
+---+----------------+
|id |ids_within_group|
+---+----------------+
|1  |[1, 2, 3]       |
|4  |[4, 5]          |
|6  |[6]             |
|8  |[8, 7]          |
+---+----------------+
```